# Visual Studio MSI Installer - Not making registry changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I created a Visual Studio MSI Project that runs an custom EXE (which is good).  In this exe, there is some code to add additional registry changes to add entries into Internet Options (mainly Local Intranet and Trusted Sites under Security).  When the exe is run by itself (and in the debugger), it executes as expected (and puts the correct registry entries in their correct location).  However, when the MSI executes the exe file, this part gets ignored even though it runs (I've added Console.Writelines everywhere).

I've been beating my head over this for 2 days and if anyone has had experience with this, a correct direction would be great.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: i guess someone didn't like my question or the fact I discovered what the answer was... I wonder why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't realize that there is a "Registry On Target Machine" option inside of the MSI builder for Visual Studio.  All I had to do is right click the project > view> Registry.

There I just had to map out the values in the right places.

Thank you for everyone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

Shelling out to an EXE from an MSI is not considered "good".   As I recall, one of the many limitation of Visual Studio Deployment Projects (.VDPROJ)  is that custom actions are scheduled with impersonation.  If the MSI is being invoked from a standard user context  UAC elevation won't help because the standard user context is impersonated.

If you want a reliable, best practices based installer, you should use the Registry table.  Of course the problem there is another one of the annoying limitations of VDPROJ is that every registry value is a key file of it's own component and you quickly get into self repair hell.

I'd really suggest starting over with another toolset. I  can think of several good ones.